# Axis scales in the f-curve editor

Tags: interface, graph-editor

Is is possible to decouple x and y zoom factors in the fcurve editor? I'd like to grow to y-scale without affecting how many frames are visible.

Comment: Ctrl+MMB and move the mouse up or down, is that what you mean?

Comment: grab the end point on the vertical ruler ( Y scale ) and move it down to zoom in

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the curve editor grab and slide the end points of the Y scale to zoom in and out :

[image]

Comment: Do you know how to do it in a script?

Comment: @NoamPeled at the moment no

Comment: Also (at least in the latest 2.80 beta) you can hold Ctrl and Middle-Mouse click and drag up and down anywhere within the graph.