# Graph editor view zooms too far

Tags: interface, workflow, graph-editor

My problem is that after scaling the axes to show the curve I wish to work on in the Graph Editor, as soon as I try to grab a handle on the curve (or click anywhere in the window), the view zooms right in to show a fraction of a frame. The editor is essentially unusable as a result.

This video shows what I mean: https://vimeo.com/231747708

I've tried opening a new instance of Blender and copying over the meshes in case the original file was corrupted but makes no difference.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28635/axis-scales-in-the-f-curve-editor. As an alternative use Normalize in Graph editor if you want to preview all the curves at once no matter on their scale.

Comment: I can't reproduce what you are experiencing. Please add more information. What OS are you using? What Addons are enabled? Does this happen in other versions of blender?

Comment: Thanks for the replies - Mr Zak I tried scaling as suggested in the previous question and the Normalize switch makes no difference.

Comment: Cegaton - I'm running a Dell XPS-15 with Windows 10 and have enabled Node Wrangler, Images as Planes and Archimesh add-ons, everything else is straight out of the box.  I've tried Blender versions 2.78 and 2.78.5 and it happens in both.  I've also opened a second instance of Blender and copied across the objects in case the file was corrupted and also created an entirely new animation file but the problem still exists in both cases.  I appreciate everyone's help with this.